# Please, help me understand what they say in video

Tags: pronunciation

There's a dialog in [this promo clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLCcE0uq__s&list=UUPWQWav6BpPvtanCtloXkiw) (The Vampire Diaries) starting on **00:15** where Stefan says something but because of the song on the background I can't really hear it:

> ... rather ... clean up two corpses today?

or something like that. And then Enzo replies to him:

> I'm **brutish**.

But I'm not sure either, maybe he says:

> I'm **British**.

Please, help me figure this out.

Many thanks. :)

Comment: *brutish...* because it's The Vampire Diaries! :)

Comment: @Maulik V, thx a lot :))))) and what about Stefan's sentence?

Comment: Does not sound clear to me as well. Blame the song for sure.

Comment: why downvote? I've seen such questions here where the pronunciation is not understandable to the OP.

Comment: I hear, "You'd rather out and clean up two corpses today?" "I'm brutish." I think the trailer's just trying to play with words.

Comment: @Damkerng T., thank you very much. I don't know if I can make another question right here, but what does it mean "to be out", when he asks:"You'd rather out"?

Comment: I totally lack the context (the only thing I know about this show is its title). Though it's possible that he was saying "You'd rather be out", which makes sense, I couldn't hear "be". I guess that "You'd rather out" can imply "go out" and "expose" (themselves? i.e. let people know that vampires do exist, probably) in the context. The most subtle syllable in that utterance is "and". It could be either "to" or "and" or even nothing there!, but I think "and" makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You would rather not clean up two corpses today?* is possible.

--*I'm brutish.*

Comment: I don't think it's just possible; I think it's right! +1

Comment: I just learned that Michael Malarkey is an American-British actor (and singer). So probably, "I'm British" is not too far a stretch. (Or he tried to make it sound like both *British* and *brutish* at the same time, even.) I tried the clip again, and now I can hear "Really rather not clean up two corpses today?" "I'm British." (and "brutish" at the same time :-)